# Output in other activity does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-intent

**My Project**: 
Input in Mic and see Output in second Activity.

**Where I stuck?** 
What I actually can do is to speak in the mic - see the output and jump directly in the second activity. 
But what I want is to see the output within the second activity.

**My MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView voiceInput;
    private ImageView speakButton;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        voiceInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);
        speakButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                askSpeechInput();
            }
        });
    }

    private void askSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Sprechen Sie was ein");
        //tent.putStringArrayListExtra("result",resultat);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
                    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Zweites.class);
                    intent.putExtra("resultat", result.get(0));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
            }

        } }}
```

**My SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList resultat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zweites);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("resultat");

    }
    }
```

If you´re wondered how the SecondActivity.xml looks like where I want the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="You said that?"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="Yes"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="193dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/No"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/zweiteja"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClick8"
        android:text="Nein"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.761"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="193dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewsecondactivity"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout > <br>
```

Here is the picture how it actually looks like: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlfSN.png

What I want 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkrXT.png

If you need more informations please let me know. 
I hope you guys knows what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in the oncreate function of the second activity

```
.....
String text = intent.getStringExtra("resultat"); 
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewsecondactivity);
tv.setText(text);
```

Comment: Thank you so so much this was a really stupid question be honest.
Now I got a last short question: You know which code part in the MainActivity is responsible for the first output? Because now I got two outputs of the input.

Comment: In the onActivityResult function of the main activity, the output is displayed by this line voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));

Comment: So that means I have to replace this function with another function?

Comment: No, If you do not want anything displayed in your mainactivity you can comment out the line that displays the output or delete it.